# How do I get NetBeans to recognise SHTML files?

Tags: netbeans, ssi, shtml

I wan't to include a generic header and footer on my web pages. I don't know php yet and the server doesn't run java, jsp, servlets etc, so I've been told to use SSI, i.e. an include statement. In order for it to work I had to rename index.html to index.shtml and include 
< !--#include file="someFile.html" --> (no space before the ! just put it in as it wasn't showing up in question as it looks like a comment)
This works perfect on the server, but my problem is netbeans does not include the header or footer when run in the format!!
Does anyone know how to configure netbeans 8 to allow this format? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `<!--#include="someFile.html"-->` try `<!--#include virtual="someFile.html"-->`. By the way, what do you mean by Netbeans not recognising SHTML files?

Comment: Sorry I mean when I run/execute the shtml file in netbeans, the header I have included is not shown. The include statement is correct as it is working perfect on the main web server(just not locally on netbeans) I believe it is something to do with changing a .htaccess file and I have set netbeans to show all hidden files, but still cannot find this file to change it!

Comment: I assume your local server is running. Eg. Apache. I just set up a php app in NetBeans and they are working for me. Make sure your include paths are correct.

Comment: The SHTML is working fine for me _without_ PHP, that's strange, what version of netbeans are you on? Does the static `.shtml` display on the browser (Without Any Includes). I'm on **netbeans 8** and I use **xampp**. I'll upload my PHP Application Project here. Check to see if `template.shtml` will run. [PHP Example](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6g4motnun31ibg8/PhpProject1.zip)

Comment: **Note** - It's a PHP Application, but it doesn't use PHP, a Web Application is designed for Java, Servlets & JSP etc.., So are you trying to replicate your server environment to a local environment? If so I'd go with PHP Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meant to answer this way back, but I didn't have XAMPP running! Schoolboy(girl) error! Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Please describe the actual answer here for future reference of others looking into same issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand sanfor, but I didn't have XAMPP switched on as suggested by PalinDrome555, that was the answer, the server wasn't running, but with XAMPP switched on it worked fine!